# cabybara-webkit + rspec: Records are not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, acceptance-testing

I'm new to the integration testing, although I've done a lot of unit tests for my models and controllers. But now I want to test the whole stack. (I don't want to use Cucumber, since there is no customer and I can read code)

Here my (simplified) spec

```
describe ArticlesController, "#show" do
  before do
    @article = Factory :article, :title => "Lorem ipsum"
  end

  it "should show the article page" do
    visit article_path(:id => @article)
    page.should have_content("Lorem ipsum")
  end
end
```

The spec passes, but once I add `:js => true` to `it "should show the article page", :js => true do`, an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` gets thrown. If I disable `use_transactional_fixtures` in my config, it works again, but that breaks alot of other tests. Is there another solution or can I disable the transactional_fixtures just for my integration tests?

Thanks for reading! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `use_transactional_fixtures` = false for integration tests. As you found, this causes problems for other tests that assume your tables are empty to start with.

You might try the [database_cleaner](http://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem. A typical configuration in `spec_helper` would look like so:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  c.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But I had to use `.before(:each)` and `.after(:each)`.