# FactoryGirl-created record is not in database during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I'm trying to save users to the database and test that I can view the user's profile page with the following spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "profile page" do
    before { visit '/#/user' }

    it { should have_content("Name") }
    it { should have_content("Email address") }
    it { should have_content("Mobile phone") }
    it { current_path.should end_with('#/user') }
  end
end
```

This is my user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :service_company do
    name     "Service Company Test"
  end

  factory :yard do
    name     "Yard Test"
  end

  factory :service_company_account do
    association :yard, factory: :yard
    association :service_company, factory: :service_company
  end

  factory :user do
    name     "Pawan Raj"
    email    "pawan@example.com"
    phone    "5125552343"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    association :service_company_account, factory: :service_company_account
  end
end
```

In my users controller in the get_logged_in_user action (which is called in the above test), the Users table is always empty even after the create, and I can't understand why. When I look at the test.log file, the database seems to be saying the user already exists, but then it seems to insert the new user anyways. So one way or another, I would think the user SHOULD exist after this create() call. I probably have some fundamental misunderstanding of how FactoryGirl is supposed to work:

```
D, [2014-07-31T02:04:12.784184 #37634] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mUser Exists (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('pawan@example.com') LIMIT 1
D, [2014-07-30T18:30:41.624291 #37146] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "phone", "remember_token", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-07-30 23:30:41.622815"], ["email", "pawan@example.com"], ["name", "Pawan Raj"], ["password_digest", "$2a$04$VbyWKSjHxAv1C1K7ZGqIh.RZzO/wbLhimQuLrdjVPTcStoGuFcKra"], ["phone", "5125552343"], ["remember_token", "529ae9a893f14df202410268095dde8e64670980"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-30 23:30:41.622815"]]
D, [2014-07-31T02:04:12.788341 #37634] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  UPDATE "service_company_accounts" SET "updated_at" = $1, "user_id" = $2 WHERE "service_company_accounts"."id" = 302  [["updated_at", "2014-07-31 07:04:12.785914"], ["user_id", 2848]]
D, [2014-07-31T02:04:12.788696 #37634] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
```

Also, for the record, this does all work fine when I use the site by hand. So it's a testing problem.

EDIT: This is the entirety of my spec_helper.rb file in case it helps shed any light on the situation:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'capybara/angular'
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'mailchimp'
  require 'paperclip/matchers'

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    config.order = "random"
    config.include Capybara::Angular::DSL
    config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure but I think you have problem with shared connection (you can google the problem). FactoryGirl creates user successfully but it is not visible in your app. Try to add this [code](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/470808) to the end of your `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: I'll give that a try. Also, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250739/factorygirl-creates-user-but-save-point-is-released-before-test-starts) question that seems to have a similar problem to mine as I look closer at the log. The "RELEASE SAVEPOINT" action seems to occur before the sign-in happens, which I assume means that the database is cleared before the test is able to log int the test user. Is there a way to change when that happens?

Comment: OK, that code didn't seem to work, assuming I am supposed to add it to the very end of the file, outside of any blocks. I get `Exception encountered: #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished>`

Comment: What Capybara driver are you using (one that supports Javascript?) and what is use_transactional_fixtures set to?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of capybara-angular (although I've also tried with just regular capybara with no luck). My capybara version is 2.1.0. The default_driver and javascript_driver are both set to poltergeist, and `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cabybara-webkit + rspec: Records are not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249827/cabybara-webkit-rspec-records-are-not-available)

Comment: It looks like you're right. That seems to get me oh-so-close to a fix, but the problem is that those before and after blocks from what I can tell only run once per spec file (I think?)... So in the User pages test above, for example, two the last two tests are still telling me that the user already exists in the database.

Comment: So I changed the `config.before(:suite)` to `config.before(:each)`, and it technically fixed the problem... but now the user never exists in the database during my test. :( There's no winning...

Comment: What is `DatabaseCleaner.strategy` set to? If it's `:transaction`, change it to `:truncation`.